# How efficient is passing an object over doing a get?

Tags: python, django

I have a view function which does a get on objects(say A,B & C) using their Ids.
This view function calls a local function.

Should I be passing the objects to the local function or should I pass the Ids and do a get again there? Which is more efficient?
Which is a bigger overhead, passing an object or retreiving an object using get?

Comment: Pass object reference.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would think there is any overhead in passing an object into a function. That will always be cheaper than querying it from the database again, which would mean constructing the query, calling the database, and instantiating something from the result.

The only time you would definitely need to pass IDs rather than the object is in an asynchronous context like a Celery task; there, you want to be sure that you get the most recent version of the object which might have been changed in the DB by the time the task is processed.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the python object has no overhead, while passing the `id` repeating the `get()` is going to incurr a database lookup which is much more costly.

However it depends on the particular case which one should be preferred. Consider a multiuser case in which two users modify the same object:

```
from django.db import models

class Movie(models.Model):
    coolness = models.IntegerField()
    times_modified = models.IntegerField()
```

A view function might call some heavy computation to calculate coolness from a request:

```
def update_coolness(delta_coolness, id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=id)  # Read object from database
    movie.times_modified += 1
    movie.save()
    time.sleep(5)  # Heavy computation
    movie.coolness += delta_coolness*4  # Very cool movie
    movie.save()
```

If multiple users execute this query at the same time, the results are likely to be because of traditional [parallel computing problems](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/beautiful-concurrency/2-a-simple-example-bank-accounts).

You can avoid saving the wrong coolness value by repeating the get request, or simply [refreshing the object](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/models/instances.html#refreshing-objects-from-database):

```
time.sleep(5)  # Heavy computation
# movie = Movies.objects.get(pk=id)  # make sure we have the newest version
movie.refresh_from_db()  # make sure we have the newest version 
movie.coolness += delta_coolness*4  # Very cool movie
movie.save()
```

Which massively reduces the timeslot in which other users could interfere with your computation. However the clean solution is to use `transaction.atomic` which will lock the item during the process:

```
from django.db import transaction

def update_coolness(delta_coolness,id):
    with transaction.atomic():
        movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=id)  # Read object from database
        movie.times_modified+=1
        movie.save()
    time.sleep(5)  # Heavy computation
    with transaction.atomic():
        movie.refresh_from_db() # make sure we have the newest version
        movie.coolness += delta_coolness*4  # Very cool movie
        movie.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments around in this way is quite cheap: under the hood, it is implemented in terms of a single additional pointer. This will almost certainly be faster than invoking the django machinery again, which for a lookup by ID has to involve a (still fast, but relatively slower) dictionary lookup at minimum, or if it doesn't do caching, could involve requerying the database (which is going to be noticeably slow, especially if the database is big).

Prefer passing local variables around where possible unless there is a benefit to code clarity from doing it otherwise (but I can't think of any cases where local variables wouldn't be the *clearer* option), or if the "outside world" captured by that object might have changed in ways you need to be aware of.